# The product of two disjoint cycles is commutative proof.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

This is my attempt at showing that the product of two disjoint cycles is disjoint. That is if we have $\sigma$ a $\sigma'$ two disjoint permutations then $\sigma \circ \sigma' = \sigma' \circ \sigma$.

Suppose $\sigma$ is a $k$-cycle and $\sigma'$ is a $k'$cycle. We have then:

> For $\sigma$: $\sigma(a_1)=(a_2)$, $\sigma(a_2)=(a_3)$ ...
>   $\sigma(a_{k-1})=a_k$ and $\sigma(a_k)=(a_1)$, and let's fixed the
>   others.
>
> For $\sigma'$: $\sigma'(b_1)=(b_2)$, $\sigma'(b_2)=(b_3)$ ...
>   $\sigma'(b_{k'-1})=b_{k'}$ and $\sigma'(b_{k'})=(b_1)$

Now let define $\sigma_1=\sigma \circ \sigma'$. As $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ are disjoint, we have:

> $\sigma_1(a_1)=(a_2)$, $\sigma_1(a_2)=(a_3)$ ...
>   $\sigma_1(a_{k-1})=a_k$,  $\sigma_1(a_k)=(a_1)$ and also
>   $\sigma_1(b_1)=(b_2)$, $\sigma_1(b_2)=(b_3)$ ...
>   $\sigma_1(b_{k'-1})=b_{k'}$,$\sigma_1(b_{k'})=(b_1)$.

Finally, let define $\sigma_2=\sigma' \circ \sigma$. As $\sigma'$ and $\sigma$ are disjoint, we once again have:

> $\sigma_2(a_1)=(a_2)$, $\sigma_2(a_2)=(a_3)$ ...
>   $\sigma_2(a_{k-1})=a_k$,  $\sigma_2(a_k)=(a_1)$ and also
>   $\sigma_2(b_1)=(b_2)$, $\sigma_2(b_2)=(b_3)$ ...
>   $\sigma_2(b_{k'-1})=b_{k'}$,$\sigma_2(b_{k'})=(b_1)$

Hence:

> $\sigma_1=\sigma_2$ which means that $\sigma \circ \sigma' = 
>  \sigma' \circ \sigma$.

My proof looks very messy to me, and I am unsure if it's correct.

Comment: It would be helpful if you defined what "disjoint permutations" meant.

Comment: Your solution is fine.

Comment: @CatalinZara As English isn't my mother tongue, I will cite a Wikipedia article hoping it will clear up the confusion: "This alternative notation describes the effect of repeatedly applying the permutation, thought of as a function from a set onto itself. It expresses the permutation as a product of cycles corresponding to the orbits of the permutation; since distinct orbits are disjoint, this is referred to as "decomposition into disjoint cycles"". Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation

Comment: @JohnMayne : So you meant "disjoint cycles," and not "disjoint permutations." Not every permutation is a cycle ...

Comment: @CatalinZara Yes, my bad. I will edit my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an outline for a proof for the general case of disjoint permutations.

It's useful to define "disjoint" carefully.

Given two permutations $\sigma_1,\sigma_2:X\to X$, we say that they are "disjoint" if, for all $x\in X$, either $\sigma_1(x)=x$ or $\sigma_2(x)=x$.

Define $X_i=\{x\in X\mid \sigma_i(x)\neq x\}$, for $i=1,2$. Then $X_1\cap X_2=\emptyset$ means that the $\sigma_i$ are disjoint.

Now, show that if $x\in X_i$ then $\sigma_i(x)\in X_i$.

Finally, use these to prove that $(\sigma_1\circ \sigma_2)(x)=(\sigma_2\circ\sigma_1)(x)$ for any $x$ by proving it for each case $x\in X_1$, $x\in X_2$, and $x\in X\setminus (X_1\cup X_2)$.